# How is the Cognitive Process described according to Buddhism? How does it relate to modern Cognitive Psychology?

Tags: pratityasamutpada, mind-and-matter

How is the mind matter process described and explained according to the Buddhist teachings? How does it related to Cognitive Psychology? How is the next moment created from the current? What is the mechanism behind it? How does this process sustain its self? What are the variation with regard to this if any?

Comment: You have many questions, I'd suggest splitting them into two.

Comment: Read the buddha and his teachings by narada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cognitive Process in Buddhism: Paticca-samuppada

Modern Science: Mental Modules come close to what the Buddha described. It was one of the topics in Robert Wright's course mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

As for your second question, the relation between the Buddhist teaching and cognitive psychology is a topic researched by Robert Wright and presented in this course: https://www.coursera.org/course/psychbuddhism

Comment: Great course!!!

Comment: You chose the correct answer as one that refers to this answer. Why wouldn't this answer qualify for being the correct answer? Peculiar!